# Remove element from

Tags: javascript, arrays, shift

I am trying to remove first element from an array without using any methods recursively. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr=[1,2,3,4];
function rem(arr){
let res=[];
if(!this.index)  // optional if index is maintaining in outside
    this.index = 0; // optional, this would get created as a global variable & make sure that you haven't use this variable in somewhere else.
if(arr.length>1){
    if (this.index<arr.length-1){
        arr[this.index]=arr[this.index+1];
        this.index++;
        return rem(arr);
    }
    else{
        this.index = undefined; // optional, make it to initial state
        arr.length--;
        return arr;
    }
 }
 this.index = undefined; // optional, make it to initial state
 return res;
 }
```

Comment: hope this answer helps to fix your issue.

Comment: you can pass it as a second argument of that function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove elements from an array, you usually use `array.splice(startingPosition, howMuchElementsYou'dLikeToRemove)`, you can't `decrement` the array and remove elements from it, like you did in your post.

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but, something like this might help you:

```
let arr=[4,2];
function rem(arr){
// If the arr length is higher than 2 (which means 3+), delete the first element leaving
// only two elements in the array.
 if(arr.length > 2) {
   // Remove - splice - the FIRST element in the array. (0 - means first element, 1 - is
   // how much elements from that position you'd like to remove from the array).
   arr.splice(0, 1)
 } else {
   // Call the function
   rem(arr);
 }
}
// Call the function
rem(arr);"
```

If this isn't related to your question, please edit your question better so we understand what exactly you need. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: i write without using any methods and splice too